# Using Mocha to test props on a rendered SVG component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, svg, mocha.js

I am writing unit tests for a method that renders two different SVG `<line/>` elements (each line is hereby referred to as a 'wick'). The props passed to this method are: `{x1, x2, y1, y2}`, and the method is invoked twice in the `render()` method of my `<Candle />` component.

When writing tests for this component as a whole, I am struggling to test *both* wick's props. This is what I'm currently running:

```
it("should render a wick line", () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<Candle {...baseProps}/>);
  const wicks = wrapper.find("line");
  const values = [
    {
      x1: 5,
      x2: 5,
      y1: 30,
      y2: 5
    }, {
      x1: 5,
      x2: 5,
      y1: 10,
      y2: 5
    }];

  wicks.forEach((wick) => {
    expect(wick.prop("x1")).to.eql(values.x1);
    // expect(wick.prop("x2")).to.eql(5);
    // expect(wick.prop("y1")).to.eql(values.y1);
    // expect(wick.prop("y2")).to.eql(5);
  });
});
```

This test fails as it stands:

```
1) should render a wick line
     primitives/candle
     expected 5 to deeply equal undefined
```

As seen in my comments, I've tried anticipating a designated numeric value as well as testing the appropriate keys in my `values` array of objects.

Is there a better way to go about this? Or am I missing something obvious in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `expect(wick.prop("x1")).to.eql(values[0].x1);`

you could replace the forEach with this

```
wicks.forEach((wick, i) => {
  expect(wicks[i].prop("x1")).to.eql(values[i].x1);
  expect(wick.prop("x2")).to.eql(5);
  expect(wick.prop("y1")).to.eql(values.y1);
  expect(wick.prop("y2")).to.eql(5);
})
```

Comment: Both `prop` and `props` run a test, only difference being that `props` returns this failing message: `expected { Object (x1, x2, ...) } to deeply equal undefined` ... instead of my initial fail, which was closer to my desired output.

Comment: `prop[key]` seems more suited to testing individual props. http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/prop.html

Comment: This warning from my initial post indicated (to me) that I am not pulling the correct property off of `values`, instead of the other way around: `expected 5 to deeply equal undefined`

Comment: yeah, I just updated it. I had it backwards. you might want to consider using a for loop instead of a forEach

Comment: An issue with your updated solution is the index assignment of `values` will neglect the second Obj passed into my array, which I need to test.